# Using the literal '@' with a string variable

Tags: c#, string

I have a helper class pulling a string from an XML file. That string is a file path (so it has backslashes in it). I need to use that string as it is... How can I use it like I would with the literal command?

Instead of this:

```
string filePath = @"C:\somepath\file.txt";
```

I want to do this:

```
string filePath = @helper.getFilePath(); //getFilePath returns a string
```

This isn't how I am actually using it; it is just to make what I mean a little clearer. Is there some sort of .ToLiteral() or something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you have to worry about it if you already have the value. The @ operator is for when you're specifying the string (like in your first code snippet).

What are you attempting to do with the path string that isn't working?

Comment: wow... too long at the computer today... the xml file path was just wrong. 

There is absolutely no reason I would need to do what I was trying to do, thanks for setting me straight... I need to go to bed!

Comment: Yeah the @ only escapes values you can't legally type into a string constant. They don't need escaping when they are already in a variable as you dont have two characters for \n in your string you have one new line char.

Comment: I was facing same issue but in last I found my connection string was wrong. Your answer made me to check the connection string. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understand. In your example: if `helper.getFilePath()` returns `"c:\somepath\file.txt"`, there will be no problem, since the `@` is only needed if you are explicitely specifying a string with "".

When Functions *talk to each other*, you will always get the literal path. If the XML contains `c:\somepath\file.txt` and your function returns `c:\somepath\file.txt`, then string filePath will also contain `c:\somepath\file.txt` as a valid path.

Answer (score 3):

The @"" just makes it easier to write string literals.

[string (C# Reference, MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

> Verbatim string literals start with @ and are also enclosed in double quotation marks. For example:
>
> > `@"good morning"  // a string literal`
>
> The advantage of verbatim strings is that escape sequences are not processed, which makes it easy to write, for example, a fully qualified file name:
>
> > `@"c:\Docs\Source\a.txt"  // rather than "c:\\Docs\\Source\\a.txt"`

One place where I've used it is in a regex pattern:

```
string pattern = @"\b[DdFf][0-9]+\b";
```

If you have a string in a variable, you do not need to make a "literal" out of it, since if it is well formed, it already has the correct contents.

Answer (score 2):

In C# the @ symbol combined with doubles quotes allows you to write escaped strings. E.g.

```
print(@"c:\mydir\dont\have\to\escape\backslashes\etc");
```

If you dont use it then you need to use the escape character in your strings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx

You dont need to specify it anywhere else in code. In fact doing so should cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it backwards. The @-operator is for turning literals into strings, while keeping all funky characters. Your path is already a string - you don't need to do anything at all to it. Just lose the @.

```
string filePath = helper.getFilePath();
```

Answer (score 1):

The string returned from your helper class is not a literal string so you don't need to use the '@' character to remove the behaviour of the backslashes.