# C# @ operator (not for string literals)

Tags: c#

What does the `@` in this mean (I know it's using an obsolete .NET Framework 1.1 ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings)?

```
@ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["some_setting"];
```

This is NOT a string literal: [Using the literal '@' with a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120763/using-the-literal-with-a-string-variable)

The actual code:

```
_scale_id_regex = @ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ScaleIdRegEx"];
```

In a regular .cs file which is part of a Windows Service and `_scale_id_regex` is just a private string in the class, so ASP.NET and Razor are not involved.

Comment: Where'd you see this? It'd be more common to see this type of usage in a Razor source file (.cshtml) then a C# source file.

Comment: @sellmeadog - You may have to use this in LINQ too, see my answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's called a *verbatim identifier*. It allows you to name variables after reserved words. e.g.

```
string @string = string.Empty;
object @object = new object();
int @int = 1;
...
```

The code you have is valid, but I don't believe `@` services any real purpose there. Since this got upvoted faster than I could refresh my page, here's what the ECMA C# Language Specification, section 9.4.2 says.

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is
>   useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The
>   character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier
>   might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the
>   prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim
>   identifier.

The code you posted is valid because this is allowed by the language specification, albeit discouraged.

> [Note: Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords is
>   permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style. end note]

Comment: This is interesting. What is the `@` doing in the OP's question? It almost seems like the compiler ignores it.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I hear what you're saying, I've used RAZOR quit a bit, but I don't think this is exclusively RAZOR, it works in a regular console application.

Comment: The language specification allows this for identifiers that are not keywords, but it is discouraged by the ECMA language specification. I updated my answer to provide clarification.

Comment: Every once in a while I'm floored by what I learn from SO. Thanks for the info @DavidAnderson

Comment: @DavidAnderson I thought to use a verbatim it had to prefix a LHS identifier, rather than a RHS value, though. Doesn't it? I guess I could be wrong there

Comment: I'm thinking the original author may have copied this syntax from another app or an online example - there are other cases in the same code without it - which is what really confused me.  I have never seen this before.  The real difficulty is that you cannot find this kind of thing easily with a Google Search (even this helpful Q on SO will not end up being findable when you search for @ prefix no matter what quoting you try) - I believe the @ is discarded from indexing like most punctuation.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt the example given in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx indicates that `@nonreservedidentifier` and `nonreservedidentifier` are equivalent and gives and interesting Unicode example to demonstrate it for reserved identifiers.

Comment: If you can't find something in the Web about C#, the next best place is to check the ECMA specification. You can also find it on Msdn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: @CadeRoux well i understand that part, but i just thought it had to prefix an *identifier*, rather than a value, like above

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt That is how it is indended to be used, but the language specification does not disallow its placement on non-keyword identifiers (and it makes note if it). The C# compiler team isn't going to enforce a language specification rule in the compiler if that rule doesn't exist in the spec. :)

Comment: @DavidAnderson I get that, even. But `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["whatever"]` isn't really an *identifier* at all. Though I guess I don't know the exact definition of identifier. But it isn't used to *name* anything, which is what I thought had to be true for the `@` operator to be used

Comment: An *identifier* is just a name given to something. That includes classes, structures, keywords, and other things. `ConfigurationSettings` is an indentifier, which is why the code is valid.

Comment: @DavidAnderson ok, thanks. That's what I was getting at. This code really makes no sense at all, then, lol.

Answer (score 4):

You can prefix identifiers with `@` so as to distinguish them from a reserved word etc:

```
var @class = 1;
```

(@class, for example, os mainly used in razor views for specifying css class. Otherwise, avoid using such names :)

Also useful in LINQ like `from @group in...`

Comment: tried to reverse my -1 after the OP clarified that this isn't razor, but my vote got locked in. If you'll edit your answer (something menial), ill change my -1 to a +1

Answer (score 2):

### Precusor:

**Don't downvote this** because the question said it was in a regular `.cs` class. At the time I wrote this, there was nothing in the question to indicate this wasn't included in a razor view. And given no context, it would make **much** more sense for that to be the case.

I'm keeping this answer here in case other users get here looking for what `@` might do.

### Answer:

Its a way to access server-side variables and methods from a razor view (`.cshtml`).
It's very commonly used to:

1. Read session variables:

   `@Session["something"]`
2. Access Html helper methods

   `@Html.RenderPartial("someview","somecontroller");`
3. Do exactly what you have in the question(though personally I think it's bad practice)

   `@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["whatever"];`
4. Start code blocks and use things like `foreach`

   ```
   @{
       foreach(var item in Model)
       {
           <span class="modelProperty">@Model.SomeTextProperty</span>
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: While this may be true I wonder if it's %100 accurate. It works in a regular console application too, try it out.

Comment: and whoever downvoted, I would reconsider, given that at the time I wrote this answer, there was nothing about where this code resided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The '@' symbol here is actually not a C# operator at all.  It marks the beginning of an ASP.NET [Razor-syntax](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) code block.  (But, of course, there IS C# inside your code block.)

Comment: I'm not going to vote you down since I left out the fact that this is really a straight up C# class and ASP.NET is not involved in this - it's an ordinary C# class used in a Windows Service.