# How to use the `record` as a type name and resolve the ambiguity with the `record` keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, keyword, ambiguity

How to resolve the ambiguity between the `record` type name and the `record` keyword in C#?

> I've seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421257/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-keyword-as-a-property-name) it is about 13 years ago but this option is a new feature and related more to modifiers. On that post you can't use `class` alone in context. But here you can define and use `record` every where without any prefix. you just resolve the ambiguity with single-time prefix.You can not use `class` as a property name nowhere but for `record` it is possible. Just somewhere creates ambiguity.
> [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)
> [C# @ operator (not for string literals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851540/c-sharp-operator-not-for-string-literals) 
> [@ prefix for identifiers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418227/prefix-for-identifiers-in-c-sharp)
> These SO posts are all about adding `@` before a keyword. You can not use that keyword alone(without `@`) as a variable. But this new C# feature is for resolving ambiguity. You have not to use `@` every where, but just at ambiguous situations.

Example for the difference:

```
        var @int = 3;
        int= 5;    //error❌

        var @record = 5;
        record = 5;//OK✅
```

Question example:

```
class record
{
    public record()
    {

    }

    record Name()             //ambiguity record type name with record keyword
    {
        return new record(); //Compile time error
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a C# keyword as a property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421257/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-keyword-as-a-property-name). The question title is misleading, the answer is not only for properties, but for every identifier in C#. Another answer would be to just adhere to C# naming guidelines and use PascalCase for classes, i.e `Record`

Comment: I've seen this SO question it is about 13 years ago but this option is a new feature and related more to modifiers. On that post you can't use class alone in context. But here you can define and use record every where without any prefix. you just resolve the ambiguity with single-time prefix.You can not use class as a property name nowhere but for record it is possible. Just somewhere creates ambiguity.

Comment: ```            var @int = 3;
            int= 5;//error

            var @record = 5;
            record = 5;//OK
            ```

Comment: That's because `var record = 3; record = 5;` is valid already, there's no need to use a `@` anywhere there. The new `record` keyword comes with quite a few more specificities when it means a record and when it's an identifier when compared to keywords and identifiers that have always existed like `int`, because Microsoft can't afford to break everyones code that uses `record` as an identifier anywhere

Comment: @MindSwipe, Exactly. This explanation about the difference provided to show the difference between my question-answer and the old posts(To reopen my question). This new feature is added lately. They might be similar apparently but practically there is a delicate difference between the two.

Comment: But you can use `async` as a local variable name and yet in other contexts you'll get similar errors to the above. We don't need a separate question for each (conditional) keyword.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This questions is related to all ambiguous conditions. There is no similar question on SO. This is the first

Answer (score 0):

**Just put an at-sign `@` before the `record` type.**
By placing an `@` before the type name you explicitly tell the compiler that it is a type name not a keyword.

```
class record
{
    public record()
    {

    }

    @record Name()             //✅
    {
        return new record();
    }
}
```

You can use `@` in every similar situation.

For more info refer to [Warning on lower case type names in C# 11](https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2022/04/11/lowercase-type-names.html?utm_source=csharpdigest&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=411)